# How to pass an environment variable from Cloudbuild to Dockerfile

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dockerfile, google-cloud-build

I am trying to integrate doppler secrets with my google cloud build service. However, I am getting an error in my cloud build logs: Doppler Error: you must provide a token

My Dockerfile gist: https://gist.github.com/hrshtsharma17/4387c7c624cf843c912a7f456f8c81e3

My Cloud Build file gist: https://gist.github.com/hrshtsharma17/10b184188c194e2b957291de2dfb7ea2
Note: I have already set _DOPPLER_TOKEN as a variable in trigger

I have tried to follow the integration method mentioned on the website:
https://docs.doppler.com/docs/enclave-gcp-cloud-build (Method 2)
https://docs.doppler.com/docs/dockerfile#installation

Comment: Do you need the doppler token at build time or at run time?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Actually, I am new to this setup. It seems that the doc suggests that we install the doppler package during build time and deploy the app (the last line in the docker file) using the docker file itself. So we need the env variables to be fetched and set before the app is deployed or else it will throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, I understand that you need this token only at runtime. Therefore you can simply add it in your Cloud Run deployment, not in your Docker Build

End your Cloud build file like that

```
...
    - '--platform'
    - 'managed'
    - '--set-env-vars'
    - 'DOPPLER_TOKEN=$_DOPPLER_TOKEN'

images:
  - gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/$_SERVICE_NAME
```

In addition, think to add your token in secret manager, it's more secure.